# How to use Hibernate's @Filter annotation in an @EmbeddedId property

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

### tl;dr

Can't make Hibernate filter work with an embedded id property.

Sample project to reproduce the issue [here](https://gitlab.com/yagotlima/hibernate-filter-issue-example-project)

### Actual question

I'm struggling with this query for quite a while.

Suppose the following entity mapping example:

```
@Entity
class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "client_id")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client")
    private List<CarRent> rentHistory;

    // ... getters and setters
}

@Entity
class Car {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "car_id")
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String foo;

    // ... getters and setters
}

@Entity
class CarRent {
    @EmbeddedId
    private CarRentKey carRentKey;

    @MapsId("clientId")
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Client client;

    @MapsId("carId")
    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id",  nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Car car;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String bar;

    // ... getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
class CarRentKey {
    private int clientId;
    private int carId;
    @Column(name = "date_due")
    private Date dateDue;

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

I need to fetch all Clients with theis rentHistory populated with CarRents from a certain date. The following query would work perfectly for me:

```
from Client cl
    left outer join fetch c.rentHistory as rent with rent.car = c and rent.dateDue = :date
```

But Hibernate keeps telling me to use a filter when fetching a join in the exception.

I tryed

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name="dateDueFilter", parameters= {
    @ParamDef( name="dateDue", type="date" ),
})
@Filters( {
    @Filter(name="dateDueFilter", condition="dateDue = :dateDue"),
})
class CarRent {
    // ...
}
```

but then when I run my query like:

```
EntityManager em;
// ...
Session hibernateSession = em.unwrap(Session.class);
hibernateSession.enableFilter("dateDueFilter").setParameter("dateDue", dateDue);
em.createQuery("from Client cl"
    + "left outer join fetch c.rentHistory");
List<Client> clientList = q.getResultList();
// clientList contains CarRent of all dates
```

The filter is just ignored. Same result with `condition="carRentKey.dateDue = :dateDue"` and `condition="date_due = :dateDue"`.

I use filters for other left outer joins on the same query and they work just fine. But this one relation that evolves an embedded parameter I can't find a way to make it work.

Is it possible? Are there alternatives?

PS: filtering in the where section e.g. `from Client cl left outer join fetch c.rentHistory as rent where rent.dateDue is null or rent.dateDue = :date` is not an option since my real query has other joins which results get filtered and gets really slow when I do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was misusing the @Filter annotation in this case.

Vlad Mihalcea helped me solve the problem on [my post in the Hibernate forum](https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/how-to-use-hibernates-filter-annotation-in-an-embeddedid-property/2220)

Based on his orientations I managed to solve the problem without filters using a join query with no fetch and a result transformer.

The solution for the example would be:

```
org.hibernate.query.Query<Client> q = em.createQuery("select cl, cr " + 
        "from Client cl " + 
        "join CarRent cr on cr.client = cl and cr.carRentKey.dateDue = :date")
        .setParameter("date", exampleDate)
        .unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).setResultTransformer(new BasicTransformerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public List transformList(List list) {
                Map<Serializable, Client> clientMap =
                        new LinkedHashMap<>(list.size());

                for (Object entityArray: list) {
                    if (Object[].class.isAssignableFrom(entityArray.getClass())) {
                        Client client = null;
                        CarRent carRent = null;

                        Object[] tuples = (Object[]) entityArray;

                        for (Object tuple : tuples) {
                            em.detach(tuple);

                            if (tuple instanceof Client) {
                                client = (Client) tuple;
                            }
                            else if (tuple instanceof CarRent) {
                                carRent = (CarRent) tuple;
                            }
                            else {
                                throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                                    "Tuple " + tuple.getClass() + " is not supported!"
                                );
                            }
                        }

                        if (client != null) {
                            if (!clientMap.containsKey(client.getId())) {
                                clientMap.put(client.getId(), client);
                                client.setRentHistory(new ArrayList<>());;
                            }
                            if (carRent != null) {
                                client.getRentHistory().add(carRent);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new ArrayList<>(clientMap.values());
            }
        });

List<Client> clientList = q.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, if I understood it correctly, but this:

```
em.createQuery("from Client cl"
+ "left outer join fetch c.rentHistory");
```

doesn't make use of `@Embeddable` which should be filtered.

Edit:

You need to use the `Session` you have set up. Open transaction with it and query for results:

```
hibernateSession.openTransaction();
results = hibernateSession.createQuery(...).list();
hibernateSession.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Since my @Embeddable is on CarRent how can I make use of it so the filter work properly?

Comment: On `CarRent` it would work, because there is the field that is being filtered. Just the way you did - by passing filter to `Session`.

Comment: Sorry. That was wrong in the example. Just fixed that in an edit: "rentHistory" is actually a relation with CarRent

Comment: Ahh, yeah, now i know. You are setting up `Session` but no using it. See this example: https://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example

Comment: I have added a hint, how to do it:)

Comment: Will try that now. Thanks. Just for clarification which is the correct filter definition: `condition="dateDue = :dateDue"` or `condition="carRentKey.dateDue = :dateDue"`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187873/discussion-between-ylima-and-andronicus).